# Nested index in the recursive LINQ query function

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, recursion

I have a recursive LINQ query function where it transforms the flat tree structure from the database to the hierarchy tree. Now I would like to add the index to each tree leaf. The problem is that the index has to be nested from its parent.

Here is the LINQ recursive function

```
    public IList<QuestionGroupTree> FlatToHierarchy(IEnumerable<QuestionGroupTree> list, string parentId)
    {
        return list.Where(i => i.CParentId == parentId)
            .Select((v, i) => new QuestionGroupTree {
            CNodeId = v.CNodeId, 
            CParentId = v.CParentId,
            CNodeName = v.CNodeName,
            Children = FlatToHierarchy(list, v.CNodeId),
            NodeIndex = i + 1
        }).ToList();

    }
```

As you can see I tried to get the index from the LINQ function and put it into `NodeIndex` property. But it's not stacked from its parent.

Here is the output

```
1. Customer Service
  1. MalFunction
    1. Host Failure
      1. Contact Information
      2. Models
      3. OnSet
      4. Other Service
      5. Warranty
```

And this is the one I expect

```
1. Customer Service
  1.1. MalFunction
    1.1.1. Host Failure
      1.1.1.1. Contact Information
      1.1.1.2. Models
      1.1.1.3. OnSet
      1.1.1.4. Other Service
      1.1.1.5. Warranty
2. Blah Blah
   2.1. Blah Blah
```

So I really have no idea how to get the nested index from the parent when it comes to recursion. Unlike the nested for loop where we can just simply get the parent.

Something like

```
for(var i)
  for(var j)
    for(var k)
      console.log(i + '. ' + j + '. ' + k)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change type of `NodeIndex` to string in stead of int. Then you can pass the parent index to your function and use it to create the prefix for NodeIndex.

See the example:

```
public IList<QuestionGroupTree> FlatToHierarchy(IEnumerable<QuestionGroupTree> list, string parentId, string parentIndex)
{
    var prefix = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parrentIndex) ? "" : parrentIndex+".";
    return list.Where(i => i.CParentId == parentId)
        .Select((v, i) => new QuestionGroupTree {
        CNodeId = v.CNodeId, 
        CParentId = v.CParentId,
        CNodeName = v.CNodeName,
        Children = FlatToHierarchy(list, v.CNodeId, prefix+(index + 1)),
        NodeIndex = prefix+(index + 1)
    }).ToList();

}
```